# How To Get Value From Attribute Of " li " Using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Here I am trying to get the value from li attribute i.e `id="@item1.TaskId"` present in li on load of page using Jquery. 
But, as the page is loaded and jquery is executed the value in variable i.e taskId `var taskId = $("ul").find("li").attr("id");` is undefined.
Below id my Html consisting li with id i.e `id="@item1.TaskId` as attribute

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="font-family:'Century Gothic'">
<div class="panel panel-default " id="@ViewBag.statusIdForTask" sId="@ViewBag.statusName">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align:center; font-size:16px;font-family:'Century Gothic'">@ViewBag.statusName</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="ui-sortable tasklistdiv sorttaskDP receive">
            @foreach (var item1 in Model)
            {
             <li class="ui-sortable-handle panel-style bs-callout bs-callout-default receivepanel" id="@item1.TaskId" taskid="@item1.TskAssId" style="font-size:14px;text-align:justify; @styleClass">
            }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is My Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var taskId = $("ul").find("li").attr("id");
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're probably finding some other `<ul>`.

Comment: And where are you reading taskId's value? Is it right after the var taskId line or is it in some other block of code?

Comment: after copying your information into an html, printing a hardcoded value of the attribute worked properly. Do you have data in your Model? Did you inspect your rendered html of the id attribute of the element is properly defined?

Comment: are there any `li` on the page that do not have an `id`?

Comment: `$("ul li[id]")` will find all of the li's with an `id` attribute for processing.

Answer (score 0):

jquery .each should work here.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var taskId = $("ul").find("li").each(function(){
             var id = this.id;
         });
    });
    </script>
```